# how to pass the value of <a> tag to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

First of all my question is, does a tag in html stores a value like input type = "text" does?

Secondly, I have a links like this let say:

```
<a href="#" >A</a>
<a href="#" >B</a>
<a href="#" >C</a>
```

I want to pass for each of the link their value let say A, B, C.

What i do is this:

```
  <a href ="" onClick = "sendVal(this);">A</a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendVal(letter){
      alert(letter);
    }
  </script>
```

But unfortunatelly i dont get A , but i get its href, how would i get the letter??
Any idea?

Comment: Must be pure JS or can you use Jquery ?

Comment: How do I use Jquery with that, i am not familiar with jquery at all :s

Comment: Who upvoted this highly-Google-available question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```
<a href ="#" onClick = "sendVal(this.innerHTML);">A</a>

  function sendVal(letter){
     alert(letter);
  }
```

Comment: innerText is not cross browser

Comment: Both should work just fine in IE.  If you're loading a local html page in IE, it prompts you to enable running scripts.  Make sure you click to allow scripts.  Which version of IE are you running?  It will prompt you every time you load the page.

Answer (score 0):

here you go as JS only

```
<a href ="" onClick = "sendVal(this);">A</a>

function sendVal(letter){
    alert(letter.text);
}
```

If you want cross browser compatibility i would really use jquery, otherwise you'll have to do lots of checks to see which to use.

If you are not limited to JS(as per client request) and this is a learning project you should really look at: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: did you actually try this in IE?

Comment: yea tried it works, might not work in a browser, i guess innerHTML/innerText could also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href ="#" onClick = "javascript: sendVal(this.innerHTML);">A</a>
```